# .htaccess redirection for incoming links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have recently run into a problem with the 301 htaccess redirection. 
One site, which I've no access to have added a link to my site with an unexpected URL.

At the end of the url, there is an additional `http://`

So the incoming link looks like this,

```
domain.com/featured/title.htmlhttp://
```

I want to 301 redirect it to

```
domain.com/cat/title.html
```

I added the following code to my .htaccess file and doesn't seem to work.

```
redirect 301 /featured/title.html(.*) /cat/title.html
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use regex with a `Redirect` directive, you'll need to use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /featured/title.html(.+) /cat/title.html
```

You also want to change the regex to `(.+)` so that it won't match the correct URL.